# Terraform Destroy Command shows improper plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Am New to Terraform and learning now. I have created an aws instance using terraform code which worked (I have test environment). I wiped out same instance using "`terraform destroy`" and it went successful. Now, when i try to create new instance, "`terraform plan`" shows 2 resources to be added instead of 1. below is my plan output.

```
C:\terraform>terraform plan

Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions: 

 + aws_instance.example
      id:                           <computed>
      ami:                          "ami-051f75c651d856381"
      arn:                          <computed>
      associate_public_ip_address:  <computed>
      availability_zone:            <computed>
      cpu_core_count:               <computed>
      cpu_threads_per_core:         <computed>
      ebs_block_device.#:           <computed>
      ephemeral_block_device.#:     <computed>
      get_password_data:            "false"
      host_id:                      <computed>
      instance_state:               <computed>
      instance_type:                "t2.micro"
      ipv6_address_count:           <computed>
      ipv6_addresses.#:             <computed>
      key_name:                     <computed>
      network_interface.#:          <computed>
      network_interface_id:         <computed>
      password_data:                <computed>
      placement_group:              <computed>
      primary_network_interface_id: <computed>
      private_dns:                  <computed>
      private_ip:                   <computed>
      public_dns:                   <computed>
      public_ip:                    <computed>
      root_block_device.#:          <computed>
      security_groups.#:            <computed>
      source_dest_check:            "true"
      subnet_id:                    <computed>
      tenancy:                      <computed>
      volume_tags.%:                <computed>
      vpc_security_group_ids.#:     <computed>
  + aws_key_pair.deployer
      id:                           <computed>
      fingerprint:                  <computed>
      key_name:                     "key-pair"
      public_key:                   "XXX"

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share your Terraform plan output. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,Am New to Terraform and learning now. I have created an aws instance using terraform code which worked (I have test environment). I wiped out same instance using "terraform destroy" and it went successful.Now, when i try to create new instance, "terraform plan" shows 2 resources to be added  instead of 1. below is my plan output.

Comment: Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Comment: I fixed it by adding key_name="xy-pair" in end of aws_instance.tf file and i removed aws_key_pair.tf file from terraform directory, now it worked perfectly. Help me to understand aws_key_pair role here,.

Answer (score 0):

Your Terraform plan was showing that it would add 2 resources: an `aws_instance` and an `aws_key_pair`. An `aws_key_pair` allows you to [control login access to your EC2 instance.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/key_pair.html)

This is because when you run `terraform plan`, Terraform looks at **all** of the `.tf` files in the current directory and tries to create all of the resources it finds. You were able to fix this by removing `aws_key_pair.tf` from the current directory, which made it so `terraform plan` could only find the `aws_instance` to create.

See the [terraform plan](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html) documentation for more details:

> By default, plan requires no flags and looks in the **current directory** for the configuration and state file to refresh.